# How to convert string ddmmyyyy to datetime fomat (DD/MM/YYYY) from provider IBMDA400

Tags: sql, datetime, oledb

I have a problem when I try converting data from column name:`'date'(string: ddmmyyyy ex:09032015)` to fomat datetime (DD/MM/YYYY) and I'm using provider **IBMDA400**.

I use some commands to try converting but have not been successful.

My purpose is only select data from database but Visual Studio always displays error.

**ex:**

```
Cmd1: select date(to_date(my string,'dd/mm/yyyy') from table
```

**->** In here appear error: `SQ20448: Expression not valid using format string specified for TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.`

And I changed:  `'TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'` instead of `'TO_DATE'` 
cmd2: `select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(mystring, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI')`  
**->** Error SQ20448 continue to occur.

Comment: This appears to be for Oracle. It is necessary to know the actual data type of the source column. Is it `date` or `timestamp` or `varchar2` (or something else altogether?). Once we know that an answer can be provided. By the way, It is not useful to know what your dbms server is called.

Comment: @Used_By_Already: IBMDA400 appears to be an OLEDB provider for IBM iSeries (or connection from PC to iSeries), rather than Oracle.  I agree that more information should be provided, though.

Comment: IBMDA400 and use DB2 I5/OS. have a solution to help me??? thanks

Comment: I see, sorry, I should have connected those dots but didn't. DB2 I don't have access to, but in any case knowing the DATA TYPE IS REQUIRED

Answer (score 0):

you have indicated through comments below that there are 3 string fields (for day, month and year) and that you concatenate these so they look like `09032015`

Instead concatenate in an ISO standard fashion and then convert to date.

For DB2 I would try this:

```
to_date( ( CONCAT z CONCAT '-' CONCAT Y CONCAT '-' CONCAT X) , 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
```

where

- Z = year string
- Y = month string
- x = day string

Once you have a date you can reformat it to any desired style you like.

Please note that date data types are NOT STORED in any particular format.

---

This following was prepared on the (wrong) assumption of the dbms being Oracle.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e0ac/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
    (X date, Y timestamp, Z varchar2(60))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO TABLE1 (X,Y,Z)
         VALUES (to_date('09032015','ddmmyyyy'), to_timestamp('09032015','ddmmyyyy'), '09032015')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(X, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
, TO_CHAR(Y, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
, substr(Z,1,2) || '/' || substr(Z,3,2)  || '/' || substr(Z,5,4) 
FROM TABLE1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e0ac/5/0)**:

```
| TO_CHAR(X,'DD/MM/YYYY') | TO_CHAR(Y,'DD/MM/YYYY') | SUBSTR(Z,1,2)||'/'||SUBSTR(Z,3,2)||'/'||SUBSTR(Z,5,4) |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
|              09/03/2015 |              09/03/2015 |                                            09/03/2015 |
```

Comment: My table :
create table table1(X  day , Y month , Z year varchar(60)
and I grouped  3 fields (year, month, day) as 1 column date
and then column ex: xxyyzzzz.
so now i can not convert string to datetime.

Comment: clarify your question! don't hide valuable information about the question in comments.

Comment: what are the `data types` of X Y and Z? integers or strings?

Comment: X Y Z 're strings and when i grouped them 1 field (Strings).Now column date have type ddmmyyyy (ex:09032015)

Comment: I must covert string to datetime because i wanna compare between 2 date.Because i work with sql on a new database(DB2) that so different with sql2005. :(